# Artifactory service installation issues

Tags: permissions, root, artifactory

I ahve a requirement to run a script thats only runnable with a specific user and group. The format of the command is like

```
$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/bin/installService.sh [USER [GROUP]]
```

I tried running the script as

```
$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/bin/installService.sh root root
```

But I get the following error

```
** ERROR: Only root user can install artifactory as a service
```

When I run it with sudo I get another eror

```
sudo  $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/bin/installService.sh
** ERROR: Could not change values in /etc/init.d/artifactory
```

Executing it with `sudo su` also gives the same result. Here is the entire trace

```
** INFO: Please edit the files in /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory to set the correct environment
Especially /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/default that defines ARTIFACTORY_HOME, JAVA_HOME and JAVA_OPTIONS
cp: /etc/init.d/artifactory: No such file or directory
chmod: /etc/init.d/artifactory: No such file or directory
sed: illegal option -- -
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

** ERROR: Could not change values in /etc/init.d/artifactory
```

Whats the correct syntax to run it as a root?

Any reason the file etc/init.d/artifactory file isnt copied ?